# Replace values in array based on lookup table - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, lookup

I have a long array which has shorthand ID's which I want to replace with the full values from a lookup

Here's the original array

```
const original = 
[ [ '18', 'v'],
  [ '20', 'aev'],
  [ '22', 'v'],
  [ '23', 'v'],
  [ '25', 'c'],
  [ '29', 'vv'],
  [ '30', 'c'] ]
```

The lookup

`const lookup = {'v' : 'monkey', 'aev' : 'dog', 'c' : 'cow', 'vv': 'lion'};`

The result I want to see

```
const result = 
[ [ '18', 'monkey'],
  [ '20', 'dog'],
  [ '22', 'monkey'],
  [ '23', 'monkey'],
  [ '25', 'cow'],
  [ '29', 'lion'],
  [ '30', 'cow'] ]
```

I'm not sure if I should use a map function or for loop and how this would look exactly.

I've tried multiple versions of for loops, but I can't get to the result, because I'm not returning the exact match (it picks up v (monkey) instead of the aev value (dog))

Comment: please add the code, you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const original = [ 
  [ '18', 'v'],
  [ '20', 'aev'],
  [ '22', 'v'],
  [ '23', 'v'],
  [ '25', 'c'],
  [ '29', 'vv'],
  [ '30', 'c'] ]

const lookUp = {'v' : 'monkey', 'aev' : 'dog', 'c' : 'cow', 'vv': 'lion'};  

const result = original.map(item => [item[0], lookUp[item[1]]])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Either mutate the items OR create a new (updated) array. You chose the bad of both approaches; You mutate the items in the old array and create a new array with them. Either `original.forEach(item => { item[1] = lookUp[item[1]]; });` or `const changed = original.map(item => [item[0], lookUp[item[1]]]);`

Comment: This is perfect! I guess my js skills are not up to level yet :-)
How would I return undefined values with a string like "Other"

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as an accepted answer

Comment: @Martijn `lookUp[item[1]] ?? "Other"` see [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use map with destructuring syntax

```js
const original = [
  ['18', 'v'],
  ['20', 'aev'],
  ['22', 'v'],
  ['23', 'v'],
  ['25', 'c'],
  ['29', 'vv'],
  ['30', 'c'],
];

const lookup = { 'v': 'monkey', 'aev': 'dog', 'c': 'cow', 'vv': 'lion' };

const result = original.map(([id, shorthand]) => [id, lookup[shorthand]]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array and push the desired elements on it like this:

```js
const original = [ 
  [ '18', 'v'],
  [ '20', 'aev'],
  [ '22', 'v'],
  [ '23', 'v'],
  [ '25', 'c'],
  [ '29', 'vv'],
  [ '30', 'c'] ]

const lookUp = {'v' : 'monkey', 'aev' : 'dog', 'c' : 'cow', 'vv': 'lion'};  

const result = [];

original.map((item) => {
  result.push([item[0], lookUp[item[1]]])
})

console.log(result)
```